# Past Perfect — John <had> bought a bicycle so his friend gifted him a bicycle pump

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple

All examples are mine:

**(1a)** *John **bought** a bicycle **and** his friend gifted him a bicycle pump*.
**(1b)** *John **had bought** a bicycle **and** his friend gifted him a bicycle pump*.

**(2a)** *John **bought** a bicycle **so** his friend gifted him a bicycle pump*.
**(2b)** *John **had bought** a bicycle **so** his friend gifted him a bicycle pump*.

As far as I know, (1a) & (2a) are correct.
Also, since "buying a bicycle" happened earlier than "gifting a bicycle pump", we can use Past Perfect as well. Therefore, (1b) & (2b) are correct too. Do you agree? If not, then why not?

Comment: None of them is _wrong_ - the choice of tenses depends on the point of view of the narrative.

Answer (score 2):

Past-perfect is correct, especially if you are trying to express that at some particular time, after and because of the purchase, the gift was made.

For example, for “John bought/had bought a bicycle so *on his birthday* his friend gave him a bicycle pump” I would suggest the perfect, since the purchase was completed before, possibly long before, the day.

Incidentally, “gift” as a verb is ugly and unnecessary.  Us “gave”.  If you have to emphasize the friendly nature of the transaction, say “gave as a gift” or “gave as a present”.

Comment: _John **bought** a bicycle so on his birthday his friend gave him a bicycle pump_. - from your explanation I infer that if you heard "_bought_" in this sentence, you would think the purchase and the gift happened on the same day, i.e. on John's birthday. Am I right? Thanks!

Comment: @Loviii — maybe not the _same_ day, but the use of the simple past suggests they are closely connected in time.

Answer (score 0):

I’d like to answer my own question.

Introduction:

Since “to gift” sounds bad for natives, replace it with “to give”:

> *John (had) bought a bicycle so/and his friend gave him a bicycle pump*.

1. In terms of affecting the choice of Past Simple or Past Perfect, there is no difference between “so” (which shows that the sentence is complex) and “and” (which shows that the sentence is compound).
2. In this sentence the choice of Past Simple or Past Perfect doesn’t depend on the fact that buying a bicycle happened before giving a bicycle pump, because this fact is already understood proceeding only from the actual sense of the sentence. Therefore, the roles of Past Simple and Past Perfect are not in showing the correct sequence of actions but in something different.

Main part:

*John **bought** a bicycle so/and his friend gave him a bicycle pump*. – Past Simple accents the fact that the moment of buying and the moment of giving are perceived as closely connected: both within the same situation (implying it was not like in the moment of buying there was one situation and in the moment of giving there was already another situation) and in time (as if there had been nothing significant between these two moments)

*John **had bought** a bicycle so/and his friend gave him a bicycle pump*. – Past Perfect accents the fact that the moment of buying and the moment of giving are separate from each other with something: either something that changed the situation (if in the moment of buying there was one situation but in the moment of giving there was already another situation) or in time (if that time which was between the moments, cannot be unnoticed)